# Change index col with pandas and read_excel

Tags: python, pandas

I have a excel file with 6 columns and i want use the 3 column for my index

when I print without changing the index the output like this

`df = pd.read_excel('sp500.xlsx')
 print(df.head())`

```
    close            ctm                      Date    high     low    open  
0  1831.9  1389135600000   Jan 8, 2014 12:00:00 AM  1834.7  1825.5  1830.5   
1  1833.6  1389222000000   Jan 9, 2014 12:00:00 AM  1838.7  1824.3  1831.0   
2  1836.5  1389308400000  Jan 10, 2014 12:00:00 AM  1842.1  1826.3  1832.8   
3  1815.0  1389567600000  Jan 13, 2014 12:00:00 AM  1838.0  1809.5  1837.5   
4  1832.8  1389654000000  Jan 14, 2014 12:00:00 AM  1834.0  1812.5  1815.0
```

but when i change the index like this

```
df = pd.read_excel('sp500.xlsx', parse_dates=True, index_col=3)
print(df.head())
```

i have this

```
             close   ctm           Date    high     low    open 
2014-01-08      0  1831.9  1389135600000  1834.7  1825.5  1830.5    
2014-01-09      1  1833.6  1389222000000  1838.7  1824.3  1831.0    
2014-01-10      2  1836.5  1389308400000  1842.1  1826.3  1832.8    
2014-01-13      3  1815.0  1389567600000  1838.0  1809.5  1837.5    
2014-01-14      4  1832.8  1389654000000  1834.0  1812.5  1815.0
```

each column are moved from one and my close column is my old index

Comment: It seems data dependent issue, is possible share first 10 rows excel file?

Comment: The columns up to `Date` are now shifted. Can you try using `index_col='Date'` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a column without a name. Either remove it before loading, change the column names and remove it after loading, or use something like (assuming first column is A):

```
df=pd.read_excel('sp500.xlsx', parse_dates=True, index_col=3, usecols='B:G')
```